# Using angularJS currency filter directly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to use AngularJS currency filter {{value | currency }}, but I dont want to include the whole library only for that.
Is there any way to use that filter only directly on html or JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement the angular currency filter so that you don't have to include angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html:

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}
```

In your javascript angular controller:

```
$filter('currency')(array, expression)
```

Without controller, you can use $injector to get $filter:

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
$filter = $injector.get("$filter");
var result = $filter('currency')(array, expression);
```